# Setting path in Windows 7 command prompt

Tags: windows-7, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set PATH and other environment variables?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/how-do-I-set-path-and-other-environment-variables)

How can one set the path permanently in command-prompt. I tried using the following code :-

```
set path=%path%;C:\python27
```

It works but only until the command prompt runs. When I exit and restart, the path returns to its earlier state.

**Please tell me how can I set the command path permanently in Windows 7 command prompt.**

Comment: The answers below are correct. What you did did not make the variable persistent.

Comment: @slhck: In general: Yes, you are right. However the other question was about all majors OS and thus the answer is really long. What this user was seeking is in one sentence in the last 1/3 of the answer and titled *Windows NT*. I'm not sure if a normal user knows that Windows 7 = NT 6.1.

Comment: @TeX Actually it's in the first answer, in the part where it says *Windows - GUI* or *Command Line*.

Comment: @slhck:Woops, overlooked that. You are right. +1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the Start Menu, right-click *Computer* on the right side. In the appearing window, select *Advanced system settings* in the left area - the *System properties* will appear. Select *Environment Variables...* at the bottom.

Change the *Path* variable there and it will be always active.

Comment: While this is the accepted answer, it doesn't explain how to do it _from the command prompt_. For reference, this is done using the `setx` command (as explained in the duplicated question linked above)

Comment: For further reference (as I keep coming back here whenever I need to do this), the command is `setx path "%path%;c:\newpath"` and this works without admin rights.

Comment: `SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe` brings you to the menu to revise your path.

Answer (score 6):

You need to do the following:

1. Go to `Control Panel` --> `System and Security` --> `System`
2. Click `Advanced system settings`
3. Click `Environment Variables`
4. In the `System Variables` area, locate the `Path` variable, highlight it and click `Edit...`
5. Make the required changes, Click `OK`, `OK`, `OK`

That will save your changes permanently.